# Finding the right ''algorithm'' to determine the first day of a given month

Tags: c, cs50

I was trying to make a program that shows the calendar of a given month of a particular year, but I can't really find an algorithm that does find the first day of the month.

My Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_first_weekDay(int year, int months1, int monthDays[months1])
{
    int day;
    int months2 = monthDays[months1];
    int beginning = 3;
    while(months1 > 0)
    {
        months2 = months2 + monthDays[months1];
        months1 = months1 - 1;
    }
    for (int i = 1800; i < year; i++)
    {
        if ((i % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
        {
            beginning = beginning + 366;
        }
        else
        {
            beginning = beginning + 365;
        }
    }
    day = (beginning + months2) % 7;
    return day;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./calendar year month \n");
        return 1;
    }
    int year = atoi(argv[1]);
    int months1 = atoi(argv[2]) - 1;
    int day = 0, dayInMonth, weekDay = 0, startingDay ,month;
    char *months[] = {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
    int monthDays[] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    if (argc == 3)
    {
        if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
        {
            monthDays[1] = 29;
        }
        startingDay = get_first_weekDay(year, months1, &monthDays[months1]);
        for(month = 0; month < 12; month++)
        {
            if(months1 == month)
            {
                dayInMonth = monthDays[month] + 1;
                printf("           %s %d          \n ---------------------------", months[month], year);
                printf("\n Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat\n");
                for(weekDay = 0; weekDay < startingDay; weekDay++)
                {
                    printf("    ");
                }
                for(day = 1; day < dayInMonth; day++)
                {
                    printf("%4d", day);
                    if(++weekDay > 6)
                    {
                        printf("\n");
                        weekDay = 0;
                    }
                    startingDay = weekDay;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

For example if I wanted to know the 1st month of the year 1800, it gives me as output:

```
~/calendar/ $ ./calendar 1800 1
           Jan 1800          
 ---------------------------
 Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
                           1
   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
  16  17  18  19  20  21  22
  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
  30  31
```

But not correct, as the first day of the month Jan 1800 isn't Saturday.
[Calendar 1800](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUzkJ.png)

Could somebody help me with finding such an algorithm. I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Which cs50 problem set is this? Was it not explained in the lecture? The `if (argc == 3)` block just creates needless indenting. The program exits earlier if it isn't 3 so by the time you get there it must be 3 so no need to check.

Comment: Several examples here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week

Comment: Please don't edit the code to fix errors pointed out by answers. It makes the answer invalid.

Comment: You need to be careful when testing with old years as there were some weird adjustments made to the calendar in the past, which basically makes it impossible for programs like this to work correctly. One of the example is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1752

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an off by one error in the month handling. You were printing Feb 1800.

```c
int months2 = monthDays[months1];
```

should be

```c
int months2 = 0;
```

This was easy to debug after understanding what the code does.

The code starts with Wed (`int beginning = 3;`).

It then adds to it the days of every year leading to the specified year, starting in 1800.

It then adds to it the days of every month leading up to the specified month.

So it should be adding zero for Jan 1800.

That's what it tries to do, at least. So why is it returning `6`? Well, it's easy to confirm the loop is never entered. This is correct. And it's also easy to see it's adding a non-zero number of days for the months leading up the January. Well, that's obviously wrong.

---

There's also a problem in the handling of years.

```c
(i % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0
```

should be

```c
(i % 4 == 0 && i % 100 != 0) || i % 400 == 0
```

---

Cleaned up:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static const char *months[] = {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
static const int monthDays[] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

// Returns 0 or 1
static int is_leap_year(int year) {
    return (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0;
}

static int get_days_in_month(int year, int month0) {
    if (month0 == 1) {
        int leap_days = is_leap_year(year);
        return 28 + leap_days;
    } else {
        return monthDays[month0];
    }
}

static int get_dow(int year, int month0, int day) {
    int dow = 3;  // 1800-01-01 is a Wednesday.

    // For each year up to provided year (exclusive), starting with 1800.
    while (year-- > 1800) {
        int leap_days = is_leap_year(year);
        dow += 365 + leap_days;
    }

    // For each month up to provided month (exclusive)
    while (month0--)
        dow += monthDays[month0];

    // For each day up to the provided day (exlcusive)
    dow += day - 1;

    return dow % 7;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./calendar year month \n");
        return 1;
    }

    int year   = atoi(argv[1]);
    int month0 = atoi(argv[2]) - 1;  // 0-based month
    int day    = 1;                  // 1-based day

    int dow      = get_dow(year, month0, day);
    int num_days = get_days_in_month(year, month0);

    printf("          %s %d\n", months[month0], year);
    printf(" ---------------------------\n");
    printf(" Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat\n");

    for (int i=0; i<dow; ++i)
       printf("    ");

    while (day <= num_days) {
        printf("%4d", day++);
        dow = ( dow + 1 ) % 7;
        if (!dow)
           printf("\n");
    }

    if (dow)
        printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For some odd reason, it doesn't print the right calendar for `2021 11`

Comment: hmm, [yes it does](https://godbolt.org/z/47rsz96PW)

Comment: Hmm that's weird. If I compile it it gives me for every year above 2000 the same starting day of the month

Comment: Even for `2000 1` it doesn't give the right calendar as I tried on the link u just sent

Comment: Re "*Even for 2000 1 it doesn't give the right calendar*", yes, [That is true.](https://godbolt.org/z/39zGndorf) checking what else is wrong.

Comment: Well, we see 1801 1 is off by one, so that's going to be how we find the error. And since 1800 2 is not wrong, we know it's a problem with the year logic.

Comment: It's because you use `year` where you should use `i`.

Comment: @ikgeami Thanks for your time, I see that I sometimes make these unnecessary mistakes. For example writing `year` instead of `i`. You were really kind with trying to help me further, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1800; i < year; i++)
{
    ...
    if ((i % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
}
```

It's not clear what the above formula is trying to calculate. It looks like leap year calculation, but `year` should be `i`.

The function `get_first_weekDay` expects an array for the 3rd parameter. But you are calling it as

```
startingDay = get_first_weekDay(year, months1, &monthDays[months1]);
```

Fixing these errors doesn't seem to do much. The rest of the calculation is rather confusing. I rewrote the function `get_first_weekDay`. Note that it expects an array input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_leap_year(int y)
{ return (y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || (y % 400 == 0); }

int get_first_weekday(int year, int month, int days_in_month[12])
{
    int beginning = 3; //1800, Jan, 1 is wedndsay (3)
    for (int y = 1800; y < year; y++)
        beginning += is_leap_year(y) ? 366 : 365;
    for (int m = 0; m < month; m++)
        beginning += days_in_month[m];
    return beginning % 7;
}

void print_calendar(int year, int month)
{
    month--;
    const char* months[] = { "Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun",
        "Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec" };
    int days_in_month[] = { 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 };
    if (is_leap_year(year))
        days_in_month[1] = 29;
    int first_week_day = get_first_weekday(year, month, days_in_month);
    printf("           %s %d            \n", months[month], year);
    printf(" ---------------------------\n");
    printf(" Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat\n");
    for (int wkday = 0; wkday < first_week_day; wkday++)
        printf("    ");
    for (int day = 1; day < days_in_month[month] + 1; day++)
    {
        printf("%4d", day);
        if(((day + first_week_day) % 7) == 0)
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int m = 1; m < 4; m++) print_calendar(1800, m);
    for (int m = 8; m <= 12; m++) print_calendar(2021, m);
    return 0;
}
```

[Run](https://onlinegdb.com/dlswb61K6)

Comment: Re "*It's not clear what the above formula is trying to calculate*", the number of days in the years between 1800 and the specified year

Comment: Re "*The function get_first_weekDay expects an array for the 3rd parameter*", No it doesn't. I mean, that's not even possible. Parameters can never be arrays.

Comment: Re "*The rest of the calculation is rather confusing.*", Not at all. The code starts with Wed (`int beginning = 3;`). It then adds to it the days of every year leading to the specified year, starting in 1800. It then adds to it the days of every month leading up to the specified month.

Comment: @ikegami You have posted 4 different revisions over the past hour https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70118772/revisions , but lets say you weren't confused. It did confuse me however.

Comment: Re "*You have posted 4 different revisions over the past hour*", Oh way more than that. Making the answer clearer, and adding about the second bug.

Comment: Re "*It did confuse me however.*", So why did you keep the same algorithm?

Comment: @ikegami I changed the function `get_first_weekDay`, the rest I though was okay, I didn't comb through it though.

Comment: By the way, your point is correct that the function parameter is a pointer, decorated as an array. I couldn't actually compile `get_first_weekDay(int year, int months1, int monthDays[months1])` in Visual Studio, I changed it to `monthDays[12]` which lead to problems for me. I don't know what it would do in gcc.